# Disable certain touch events on uiwebview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

My app utilizes an interactive exhibit hall floor plan via a web page that resides on my web server. I have a `UITableView` that lists all the exhibitors and selecting an exhibitor takes the user to the `UIWebView` with the exhibitors booth highlighted on the interactive floor plan. In most cases the user has to do a zoom-in gesture to see the detail exhibitor booth information in the webview. However, because their are other interactive hotspots on the floor plan a user can inadvertently select another booth while touching the screen to zoom in. I want to disable the ability for the user to select any other booth (touch event), but want to keep it so that the user can still use the zoom in gesture. Basically, I want to render the page "static" at this point so the highlighted booth remains highlighted and the user cannot select any other hotspots but can still pan the page and zoom in.

Comment: if you just want to disable your <a> links to prevent another page being loaded you can use UIWebViewDelegate webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: method and return NO.
if your page contains some another interactive features without page reloading you should try to find a method to disable all links using javascript.

Comment: The interactive floor map is embedded in the webpage via a web service from a vendor and the hotspots are done through javascript and are not links. If the page is viewed via a desktop browser the user just has to mouse over the hotspot to highlight it and see info about it. Since there is no mouse over in a mobile device, the same effect is done via touch. This is why I just want to disable tap/touch functionality and not gesture functionality so the user can still pan and zoom in as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebViewDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
   if (//link is something you want to ignore)
   {
      return NO;
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for my issue since the hotspots are actually rendered via javascript mouse over not from a URL scheme. So when I use the code above with if(([ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ]) && (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)) it doesn't help, the hotspots can still be tapped.